# How to save JPG/PNG files and have it retain correct Content-Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I am saving a picture file from a server a bucket in S3 in the following way:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://link.to/file.jpg')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
jpg_data = response.read()

storage = S3BotoStorage(bucket='icanhazbukkit')
my_file = storage.open(path_to_new_file, 'w')
my_file.write(jpg_data)
my_file.close()
```

The file gets written, but somewhere along the way the MIME context gets lost, and the saved image will return `Content-Type: binary/octet-stream` and browser will try to download instead of displaying when its URL is hit.

Any way I can mitigate this?

Comment: I'm not familar with this the library you are using, but when you are uploading a file to s3, you need to pass the content-type header in the api call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
jpg_data = response.read()
```

I believe boto loses the information about the file extension, which it uses to guess the mimetype.   So by the time you store it with

```
my_file.write(jpg_data)
```

all boto/S3 knows is that it has some sort of binary data to write.

If you replace these lines in your program:

```
storage = S3BotoStorage(bucket='icanhazbukkit')
my_file = storage.open(path_to_new_file, 'w')
my_file.write(jpg_data)
my_file.close()
```

with

```
bucket = conn.create_bucket('icanhazbukkit')
k = Key(bucket)
k.name = "yourfilename"
header = {'Content-Type' : 'image/jpeg'}
k.set_contents_from_string(jpg_data, header)
```

You can control the Content-Type by specifying it with the header param

If you want to preserve the Content-Type from your original get, you can do this:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://link.to/file.jpg')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
file_data = response.read()

bucket = conn.create_bucket('icanhazbukkit')
k = Key(bucket)
k.name = "yourfilename"
origType = response.info().gettype()
header = {'Content-Type' : origType}
k.set_contents_from_string(file_data, header)
```